# VMStat ran everyday at midnight with the time before each entry

Tags: linux, shell, cron, sh

Trying to run a VMSTAT every 10 minutes (every 600 seconds 144 times a day) but would like to append the time at the beggining of each line.

```
 0 00 * * * /usr/bin/vmstat 600 144|awk '{now=strftime("%T"); print now $0}' > /home/rory/rory_vmstat`date +\%d`
```

I keep getting a message in my mail saying:

> /bin/sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
>
> /bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file

This works in the command line: /usr/bin/vmstat 600 144|awk '{now=strftime("%T"); print now $0}' so i'm not sure whats wrong.

I'm sure its nothing too complex, I tried switching the ' and " round but no luck. Any help will be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've escaped the last % character here `date +\%d` , you likely need to do the same with the first too:

```
strftime("\%T")
```

The issue being that cron converts % to a newline and sends the text after the % to stdin of the command,  unless that % is escaped.

Comment: Thank you, that's fixed the mail issue and it creates the file, but it seems to be empty, any ideas? thanks again!

Comment: It will, eventually. You told it to run for 24 hours, outputting a line every 10 seconds. The fact that the file is empty atm is most likely buffering ;)

Comment: Thank you! I'll give it till tomorrow morning (I changed the crontab to run at 6 pm so it will definitely have entries owed)

Comment: @ROShea - you're welcome. Please tag me in responses, otherwise I won't know ;)

Comment: @tink New to this haha, It worked but the buffering issue wasn't ideal so I added stdbuf so I could have the information appended to the file in real time. Thanks for the help :) Final command was `0 00 * * * vmstat 600 144|stdbuf -oL awk '{now=strftime("\%T"); print now $0}' > /home/rory/new_buffered_rory_vmstat`date +\%d`

Comment: @ROShea - pleasure, glad you got is sussed.